# accessing sharepoint list using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

hi 
How to access sharepoint list from javascript using ajax?
I am getting 404 error everytime.

```
     var d ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
<soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">
<listName>TEST</listName>
<queryOptions></queryOptions>
<query><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">title</Value></Eq></Where></Query></query>
</GetListItems>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
```

Can someone check if Soap envelope is correct?

Comment: Using single quotes (`'`) to enclose that string would save you the trouble of having to escape all the internal quotes.

Answer (score 4):

It would be easyer to use a library instead of forging soap envelopes yourself. Try [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/), a jQuery library for SharePoint web services.

Then you just do [something like](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery.SPServices-0.5.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Announcements",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
        $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

Nice!

Comment: I agree. SPServices is really easy to use. This should be marked as the answer. And because it is JQ, it also allows for other fun things like autocomplete, etc.

Comment: if you are using jquery 1.7 and above the syntax cannot work anymore, see http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/23/jquery-library-for-sharepoint-web-services-spservices-v0-7-0-beta-1-available/. Please use    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { }); instead.